# Get the start and end position of found named entities

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am very new to ML and also Spacy in general. I am trying to show **Named Entities** from an input text.

This is my method:

```py
def run():

    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    sentence = "Hi my name is Oliver!"
    doc = nlp(sentence)

    #Threshold for the confidence socres.
    threshold = 0.2
    beams = nlp.entity.beam_parse(
        [doc], beam_width=16, beam_density=0.0001)

    entity_scores = defaultdict(float)
    for beam in beams:
        for score, ents in nlp.entity.moves.get_beam_parses(beam):
            for start, end, label in ents:
                entity_scores[(start, end, label)] += score

    #Create a dict to store output.
    ners = defaultdict(list)
    ners['text'] = str(sentence)

    for key in entity_scores:
        start, end, label = key
        score = entity_scores[key]
        if (score > threshold):
            ners['extractions'].append({
                "label": str(label),
                "text": str(doc[start:end]),
                "confidence": round(score, 2)
            })

    pprint(ners)
```

The above method works fine, and will print something like:

```
'extractions': [{'confidence': 1.0,
                'label': 'PERSON',
                'text': 'Oliver'}],
'text': 'Hi my name is Oliver'})
```

So far so good. Now I am trying to get the actual position of the found named entity. In this case "Oliver".

Looking at the [**documentation**](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities-101), there is: `ent.start_char, ent.end_char` available, but if I use that:

```
"start_position": doc.start_char,
"end_position": doc.end_char
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'start_char'

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I actually found an answer right after posting this question (typical).

I found that I didn't need to save the information into `entity_scores`, but instead just iterate over the actual found entities `ent`:

I ended up adding `for ent in doc.ents:`  instead and this gives me access to all the standard Spacy [attributes](https://spacy.io/api/span#attributes). See below:

```py
ners = defaultdict(list)
ners['text'] = str(sentence)
for beam in beams:
    for score, ents in nlp.entity.moves.get_beam_parses(beam):
        for ent in doc.ents:
            if (score > threshold):
                ners['extractions'].append({
                    "label": str(ent.label_),
                    "text": str(ent.text),
                    "confidence": round(score, 2),
                    "start_position": ent.start_char,
                    "end_position": ent.end_char
```

My entire method ends up looking like this:

```py
def run():
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
    sentence = "Hi my name is Oliver!"
    doc = nlp(sentence)

    threshold = 0.2
    beams = nlp.entity.beam_parse(
        [doc], beam_width=16, beam_density=0.0001)

    ners = defaultdict(list)
    ners['text'] = str(sentence)
    for beam in beams:
        for score, ents in nlp.entity.moves.get_beam_parses(beam):
            for ent in doc.ents:
                if (score > threshold):
                    ners['extractions'].append({
                        "label": str(ent.label_),
                        "text": str(ent.text),
                        "confidence": round(score, 2),
                        "start_position": ent.start_char,
                        "end_position": ent.end_char
                    })
```

Comment: You've combined two entity extractors:  nlp ner & beam (beam is an entity extractor as well).  Your score won't align with the proper entity -- beware!

Comment: is it not possible that nlp(sentence).ents doesn't equal the ents found with .get_beam_parses()?  Seems ambiguous to me

Answer (score 2):

If someone has come here wanting a simple answer to the question, I believe the following should do it:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
sentence = "Hi my name is Oliver!"
doc = nlp(sentence)

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(f"Entity {ent} found with start at {ent.start_char} and end at {ent.end_char}")
```